# How can I change the t-sne distance in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, dtw

I try to use `T-sne` in `R`.
I want to use dtw instead of Euclidean distance. 
How can I change the spec in `R`?

## Executing the algorithm on curated data

```
library(Rtsne)

tsne <- Rtsne(train[,-1], dims = 2, perplexity=30, verbose=TRUE, max_iter = 500)
tSNE
exeTimeTsne<- system.time(Rtsne(train[,-1], dims = 2, perplexity=30, verbose=TRUE, max_iter = 500))
```

Comment: I don't know what dynamic time warping is, but if it creates a distance matrix, you can supply it instead of it computing Euclidean distances. See `?Rtsne` for help.

Comment: You mean that i have to make a dtw distance matrix first.
The class of data X becomes a dist. 
And then 
change "is_distance=true" in Rtsne.
is that right?

Comment: @Anonymouscoward: could you turn this into an answer for a given distance metric, say `bray-curtis` or `manhattan`? Thank you!

Comment: I can post an answer, but bear in mind I'm not familiar with `Rtsne`, so I'm just plugging a matrix in.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply any distance matrix to `Rtsne` using a method of your choosing, and setting the `is_distance` flag to `TRUE`. See the **Supplying precomputed distances** section of `?Rtsne` for more info.

```
library(Rtsne)
library(vegan)

df = data.frame(A = c(4, 11, 17, 0, 2, 4, 8, 10, 2, 4),
                B = c(6, 10, 7, 2, 21, 3, 3, 0, 2, 17),
                C = c(5, 2, 3, 12, 12, 14, 0, 7, 8, 2),
                D = c(7, 16, 24, 18, 31, 8, 2, 21, 3, 13))


bc <- vegdist(df, method = "bray")
tSNE <- Rtsne(bc, is_distance = TRUE, dims = 2, perplexity = 2, verbose = TRUE, max_iter = 500)
```

Comment: perfect, thank you very much. I will keep in mind that I still have to apply it in a meaningful way ;-)